# Rmarkdown Not Producing Table Within For In Loop

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pander

I'm trying to produce an automated report using Rmarkdown. In this report I have sections with tables. The sections are produced using the following Rmarkdown. However, it refuses to produce any tables(tried using `kable` and `pander`) when I hit knit. Knit will just produce the headings, without any tables. When I use the immediate mode, I get the appropriate markdown. So what might I be doing wrong.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
for(p in names(presentations)) {
  deats <- presentations[p][[1]]
  cat('#', p, '\n')
  pander(deats)
  str(deats)
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `pander`, disable the auto `asis` results:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(pander)
panderOptions('knitr.auto.asis', FALSE)

for(p in names(mtcars)) {
  cat('#', p, '\n')
  pander(table(mtcars[, p]))
}
```
````

For more details, see the related [`Using pander with knitr` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/vignettes/knitr.html)

Answer (score 2):

When `knitr::kable()` or `pander::pander()` is not *top-level* R expression, you have to explicitly print it. You may see [this post](https://yihui.name/en/2017/06/top-level-r-expressions/) for more background information.

Comment: So how do I explicitly print stuff from `pander` or `kable`?