# Why do I not need results = "asis" to embed chunk output verbatim in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I used to think that the `results = "asis"` chunk option is needed to include any chunk output verbatim in the rendered Rmarkdown document; otherwise the output would be formatted as console output (e.g. with leading `##`).

However, several functions such as `knitr::kable()` seem to work just fine even without the `results = "asis"` option whereas the table I created manually is formatted as console output in the example below.

How does `knitr` know that the output is verbatim markdown and should be embedded as such?

My example:

````
---
title: Title
output: github_document
---

```{r}
# works without results = "asis"
knitr::kable(mtcars)
```

```{r}
# without results = "asis": formatted as console output
table <- "|col1|col2|\n|-|-|\n|a|b|"
writeLines(table)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
# works only with results = "asis"
writeLines(table)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

`results = 'asis'` tells `knitr` to *not* wrap code chunk output in a code block.

In your example 2, the output gets formatted as a code block (since there is no `results = 'asis'`):

```
## |col1|col2|
## |-|-|
## |a|b|
```

Example 3 treats the output 'as-is', which is valid markdown for formatting a table.

[image]

Some additonal examples are given in the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html).

Comment: But why does it work in the first example even without `results = "asis"`? Examples 2 and 3 represent how I thought this chunk option worked.

Comment: That is because of `pandoc` correctly recognising the pipe table generated through `kable` (which is the default `kable` output format). Mind you, this only works if `kable` is the top-level expression in your code block. There are a lot of posts here on Stack Overflow and on GH that revolve around this "feature" and that usually lead to the need to include `result = 'asis'` in expressions including nested `kable` calls or loops: see e.g. [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1109), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118052/rmarkdown-not-producing-table-within-for-in-loop).

Comment: Then I'd be curious to see what `knitr` outputs (i.e. before pandoc converts the markdown flavor to that of GitHub)... apparently there is no `keep_md` option when exporting as `github_document`.